# How to communicate data from windows(c#) to unity3d (c#,android) application?

Tags: c#, android, windows, unity-game-engine

can I achieve this using c# sockets ? or is there a better way to communicate between unity android application and .net windows application .. I don't have unity pro.

Comment: Unity5 free version is pretty much same as pro (can use all features that used to be pro only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write an Android `Java` socket code then compile it into a `Jar` file. You can then call functions in that Jar file from `C#`. That is a free way of doing this, but you must know `Java` to be able to do it. There are many resources out there if you search for *Unity Java Plugin*.

Another option is to use the **[Good ol' Sockets](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/13166)** plugin which cost `$24.95` only. That plugin works on both `iOS` and `Android` and will save you time and money.

Comment: Thanks ! the first option sounds better

Answer (score 1):

Can use System.Net.Sockets in Unity c#

Working client code c# example: (Connects to localhost:6670)
https://community.unity.com/t5/Scripting/C-TCP-IP-Socket-How-to-receive-from-server/m-p/1672318/highlight/true#M295000

From Player Settings,
might had to set "Api Compatibility Level" to ".Net 2.0" (instead of ".Net 2.0 Subset")